# Connecting Neurosky Mindwave using MATLAB and Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, matlab

I have a [Neurosky Mindwave](http://store.neurosky.com/products/mindwave-1) device and I would like to visualize and record raw data from it for further analysis using MATlab. I have tried all the free apps suggested in the Neurosky store (Brain Grapher, Mindstream, etc...) but I haven't been able to export raw data (potentially in CSV format). I have the Instrument Control Toolbox in MATlab but it hasn't been able to find the device through Bluetooth. The device itself works and I have been able to use it through its built-in Bluetooth connectivity and different software. Here is the error message that MATlab gives me when I input instrhwinfo('Bluetooth'):

```
Error using instrhwinfo (line 195)

Java exception occurred:
java.lang.NullPointerException

at com.mathworks.toolbox.instrument.BluetoothDiscovery.discoverDevices(BluetoothDiscovery.java:448)

at com.mathworks.toolbox.instrument.BluetoothDiscovery.hardwareInfo(BluetoothDiscovery.java:247)
```

Is the Mindwave simply incompatible with MATlab out of the box?

thank you in advance
-Alex

ps the formatting seems wrong in my question, I have very limited experience

Comment: The first thing I do when I see Java errors is rebooting, could you try and see whether it solves the problem?

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that tonight and give an update.

Comment: No dice. Same thing happened. :(

Comment: Are you able to connect the device properly with your pc?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I can use the software that was included with the machine, and my Mac can connect to it via Bluetooth. Just not MatLab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try neurosky matalab_dll [click for neurosky link](http://developer.neurosky.com/docs/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=matlabdll.zip) ? It connects with serial port.

Note: Also you can do it with simulink serial receive block which is under embedded coder but you also need a packet parser for seeing raw data.

Comment: That's it! Thank you infinitely. This came just in time. I was about to give up.